# Threads hang until i attach debugger

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I have a service using WCF. Internally it has a dictionary with lists that you can add to or get a subset of from different endpoints.

The code is something like this:

```
        List<Data> list = null;
        try
        {
            locker.EnterReadLock();
            list = internalData[Something].Where(x => x.hassomething()).ToList();
        }
        finally
        {
            locker.ExitReadLock();
        }

        foreach (var y in list)
        {
            result[y.proprty1].Add(y.property2); // <-- here it hangs
        }

        return result;
```

So the internalData is locked with a ReaderWriterLockSlim for all operations, readerlock for reading and writerlock for adding. I make a copy of the items inside the lock and work on this copy later.

The issue is after a while, more and more cpu-cores goes to 100% and finally is uses all cores. It can run perfectly for days and million calls before it stops.

Attaching debugger and pausing shows that one treads hang on adding to the result dictionary. But as soon as I resume all threads will continue and a lot of memory is being released.

Is there something special happening when a debugger is attached, pausing and resuming that will release something like this?

Comment: [Look at the 'Some limitations: reliability' part](http://joeduffyblog.com/2007/02/07/introducing-the-new-readerwriterlockslim-in-orcas/) the third paragraph reads a bit like what you are describing. (100% CPU hog). Is there a specific reason why you are not using `lock( internalData[Something])`?

Comment: I read a lot more than write so I want more than one reader read at the same time that wont work on just lock. Will look at your link

Comment: uhm, when you read from that list, is it possible that another thread will add something to that same list? Because as long as you aren't adding/removing stuff to/from the list you don't need to lock it. If you are reading and writing to the same lists in different threads at the same time, it might be a better idea to use something from the [Concurrent Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: oh follow up question: Have you been able to reproduce this problem while a debugger is attached? Meaning if you start the program in Visual Studio and let it run, does it lock up at some point as well?

Comment: The other endpoint is making changes to the list so I need to lock. The problem is not reproducible in visual studio, and happens intermittently on production server. I have changed to another lock and will see if it is an exception inside the reader as you pointed out in link in first comment

Comment: Please write back if changing the locking mechanism worked. If it did, consider self-answering your question with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my locks to lock(something) { code... } and the problem with hangs went away. So it looks lilke i ran into the issue Steffen Winkler pointed out in his comment. http://joeduffyblog.com/2007/02/07/introducing-the-new-readerwriterlockslim-in-orcas/